# Regular expression that separates phrases by pipe ONLY if there is no whitespace

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to write a regular expression that separates phrases by pipe but only if there is no whitespace.

For example, if I use this test string:

```
Other Suggestions|Like | Comment | Subscribe|134|58|Post |Contact Us
```

I don't want `Like | Comment | Subscribe` or `Post |Contact Us` to be separated because there is whitespace around the pipe.

I tried this regex: `(?<!\s)[^|]+(?!\s)` expecting the (?!\s) to do a negative lookaround for any whitespaces but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What language, and how are you using the regexp in it? If you use it in the delimiter in `re.split()` (Python) then you should use `\|` instead of `[^|]`

Comment: Just reverse the not here `[^|]` why in the world   ?

Comment: The problem is that putting `[^|]` in the regexp means the pipe can never be included in the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't match content, match separators and use split.

Something along the lines:

```
QString s("Other Suggestions|Like | Comment | Subscribe|134|58|Post |Contact Us");
QStringList sl = s.split(QRegularExpression("(?<!\s)\|(?!\s)"));
```

Here regex `(?<!\s)\|(?!\s)` searches for `|` that doesn't has whitespace symbols from  either side.

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8fIcd5/1)

**EDIT:** If you for some reason really need match content, I believe you could use this regex:

```
(?<=^|\|).*?(?=(?<=\S)\|(?=\S)|$)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=^|\|)` preceding with beginning of the string or `|`,
- `.*?` any symbols lasy (non greedy),
- `(?=(?<=\S)\|(?=\S)|$)` followed by end of line or `|` with conditions:

  - `(?<=\S)\|(?=\S)` - `|` should be surrounded by non witespace symbols.

Demo for content matching [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ltrtkd/1)

Answer (score 0):

You already have a great answer, but to give a straightforward answer to match `pipe` then `not-space` in order to split on it:

[`\|(?=\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/coMFNM/2)

[image]